# how to concatenate params in XSLT 1.0?

Tags: xslt

I am using an image src passed as a variable, code below:

```
    <xsl:param name="a" />

<img width="300" height="270" src="{a}" />
```

This works no problem, but I cant have the images in the root folder, I need to have them in an images folder, now I have spent a long while trying many things but how can I do this:

```
<img width="300" height="270" src="images/{a}" />
```

I tried storing "images/" as a param string then tried to concatenate it in front of {a} but no matter what I tried I couldn't get it to work. Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a dollar sign to reference your variable.

**Example**

Input:

```
<a href="testImg.png"/>
```

Transform:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:template match="a">
       <xsl:call-template name="renderImg">
            <xsl:with-param name="a" select="@href"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="renderImg"> 
       <xsl:param name="a" />
       <img width="300" height="270" src="images/{$a}" />
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<img width="300" height="270" src="images/testImg.png" />
```

Comment: Excellent answer well explained it was easy to follow your help, thank you! I could swear I tried something so similar, but I probably had a few mistakes in there. Cheers for your help and saving me time! :)

Comment: Glad to help; single symbols are an easy thing to miss when you've been trying something for a while.